# How to attach an SSL Cert to outgoing GA4 API request?

Tags: python, ssl-certificate, google-analytics-4

Does anyone know how I can attach an SSL cert to get past the corporate firewall?

The code was working around two weeks ago with these environment variables added in the code below:

```
os.environ["GOOGLE_API_USE_CLIENT_CERTIFICATE"] = "true"
os.environ['GRPC_DEFAULT_SSL_ROOTS_FILE_PATH'] = r'C:\Users\123\Desktop\authorized.pem'
```

However, the grpc message I am receiving now indicates the stream was removed.

Does anyone have a work around?

Here is the sanitized code that was previously working:

```py
import os
from google.analytics.data_v1beta import BetaAnalyticsDataClient
from google.analytics.data_v1beta.types import (
    DateRange,
    Dimension,
    Metric,
    RunReportRequest,
)
 
os.environ["GOOGLE_API_USE_CLIENT_CERTIFICATE"] = "true"
os.environ['GRPC_DEFAULT_SSL_ROOTS_FILE_PATH'] = r'C:\Users\123\Desktop\authorized.pem'
 
def sample_run_report(property_id="YOUR-GA4-PROPERTY-ID"):
    """Runs a simple report on a Google Analytics 4 property."""
    # TODO(developer): Uncomment this variable and replace with your
    #  Google Analytics 4 property ID before running the sample.
    # property_id = "YOUR-GA4-PROPERTY-ID"
 
    # Using a default constructor instructs the client to use the credentials
    # specified in GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable.
    client = BetaAnalyticsDataClient()
 
    request = RunReportRequest(
        property=f"properties/{property_id}",
        dimensions=[Dimension(name="city")],
        metrics=[Metric(name="activeUsers")],
        date_ranges=[DateRange(start_date="2020-03-31", end_date="today")],
    )
    response = client.run_report(request)
 
    print("Report result:")
    for row in response.rows:
        print(row.dimension_values[0].value, row.metric_values[0].value)
```